# Update column with subquery, filter out null values

Tags: sql, sql-update

I'm trying to update a column with subquery. But it gives an error:

> cannot update PRODUCT.AVERAGE_COST to NULL

I don't know how not to update when subquery result is `null`.

```
UPDATE PRODUCT P SET P.AVERAGE_COST = 
    (SELECT 
        SUM(C.COST)/SUM(C.QTY)
    FROM PRODUCT_COSTS C
    WHERE C.PRODUCT_CODE = P.PRODUCT_CODE 
    GROUP BY C.PRODUCT_CODE )
```

I don't want to update at all if `SUM(C.QTY)` is `0` or subquery result is `null`.
Query should run on Oracle, MySQL, MSSQL, PostgreSQL.

Comment: What relational database are you using? Oracle? MySQL? PostgreSQL? SQL Server? SQLite? Also, your table definition may be relevant. Sounds like you have a `NOT NULL` constraint on `PRODUCT.AVERAGE_COST`.

Comment: Also, please clarify what you want to do in the case when your subquery returns `NULL`. You state that you don't want to perform an update, but that seems a little strange. Some context about why you want the behaviors you're asking for would be helpful. The most likely reason you would get `NULL` would be that there are no rows to `SUM`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `WHERE` clause to your query. So it should look like:

```
UPDATE PRODUCT P SET P.AVERAGE_COST = 
    (SELECT SUM(C.COST)/SUM(C.QTY)
     FROM PRODUCT_COSTS C
     WHERE C.PRODUCT_CODE = P.PRODUCT_CODE)
WHERE
    (SELECT COUNT(1)
     FROM PRODUCT_COSTS C
     WHERE C.PRODUCT_CODE = P.PRODUCT_CODE ) > 0
AND
    (SELECT SUM(C.QTY)
     FROM PRODUCT_COSTS C
     WHERE C.PRODUCT_CODE = P.PRODUCT_CODE ) <> 0
```

You can check it in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04b90/1)

Comment: don't you need group by in bottom 2 subqueries

Comment: @DulguunLst No. `GROUP BY ` is not needed in bottom subqueries. In fact it is also obsolete in upper one.

Comment: Also, one more question. Performance wise, how good it is? Will `SUM(C.QTY)` get calculated twice? How would you improve its performance?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one if your using MSSQL:

```
UPDATE PRODUCT P SET P.AVERAGE_COST = 
(SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(SUM(C.QTY),0)='0' THEN '0' ELSE ISNULL(SUM(C.COST),0)/ISNULL(SUM(C.QTY),0) END
FROM PRODUCT_COSTS C
WHERE C.PRODUCT_CODE = P.PRODUCT_CODE 
GROUP BY C.PRODUCT_CODE )
```

Comment: OP's question suggests they don't want to update at all in this case ("I don't know how not to update when subquery result is null."). This answer updates to `0`.

Comment: `ISNULL` is also specific to SQL Server, and it's not clear whether the OP is using SQL Server. `COALESCE` is a more standard operator.

Comment: Read my query First before commenting,Please. It has a CASE expression which means if it is divided by 0 it will display 0.